# XACML regex not matching

Tags: regex, regex-negation, xacml, abac

We have an XACML file that has a lot of rules and we don't want to process all of the rules. We are trying to add a Target tag that will not apply for all rules and apply only for certain rules.

We tried with regular expression `"abc:def:gh:1234.*"` and wanted to process the rules only for attributes that match this expression

But the rules that has this pattern are not matched, we wanted to match this kind of pattern

```
"abc:def:gh:1234:test"

"abc:def:gh:1234-test"
```

Only this string pattern is matching 
`"abc:def:gh:1234.Test"` anything after 4 with "." is matching

We need to check only for beginning of string and tried

```
"^abc:def:gh:1234"
```

also we tried contains

```
"abc:def:gh:1234"
```

but none of the regex works , any help with regex is much appreciated

```xml
<Target>
  <AnyOf>
    <AllOf>
      <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abc:def:gh:1234.*</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="jpmc:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
      </Match>
    </AllOf>
  </AnyOf>
</Target>
```

Comment: What authorization engine are you using? Also this seems to be more of a regular expression issue rather than XACML itself. Have you tried evaluating the regular expression in Java?

Comment: Why don't you give a before and after. It's impossible to tell what it is you're trying to do !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using regular expressions (generally) and especially in XACML. XACML policies are meant to be easy to read. Try to use any of the following functions ([alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa) notation):

- stringEqual
- stringEndsWith
- stringStartsWith
- stringContains

Alternatively, you should process / normalize the values either in the Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) or Policy Information Point (PIP). Axiomatics (where I work) has a Groovy PIP that will let you do such things and keep your policies clean.